# What software can be used to read data from smart cards?

Tags: smartcard, software, simcard, library

I have recently got this smart card reader. In the description it says that it can be used to read data from fidelity smart cards, library cards, etc.

The technical card compatibility support is as follows:

```
Supported Smart card: microprocessor smart card ISO7816 1, 2, 3, 4 (protocols
T=0 and T=1, PPS in writing and reading phase) with MCU power supply at 1,8V,
3V, 5V
Supported memory cards: I2C bus (from 1K bit up to 1024Kbits)
Support: the secure memory (Atmel AT88SC153, AT88SC1608, SLE4418/28, SLE4432/42)
```

I do not have any specific goal in mind, just wondering it would be cool to use the card reader to read data from various cards that I have in house, library cards, transport cards, shops loyalty cards,etc

Beside the card reader what do I need to read data from a smart card?
Are there some software, coding library, to access the data from generic cards?

Thanks, any idea would help.

Comment: This is not a security question

Answer (score 6):

In the past, i have used [CardPeek](https://github.com/L1L1/cardpeek) for this. It is easily extensible through LUA and can therefore adapt to unknown cards. It presents the "files" on the card via a TreeView and offers annotations on "known" cards for the values.

It also has debugging facilities.

Comment: New location for CardPeek: https://github.com/L1L1/cardpeek

Comment: what is better, CardPeek or [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC)?